# Security Update for Spree Finding Nil for Money:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

This [security update](http://spreecommerce.com/blog/security-update-spree-2) for spree just released, but after running some Cucumber tests, I had this recurring issue:

```
undefined method `assume_from_symbol' for Money:Class (ActionView::Template::Error)
```

I searched the project repo on GH and we don't use the method. Searched the [Money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) repo and also no findings. Searched Spree and [found this](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/0e4a5db82cc083dd5913d7f85c3bf58b74e64fc7/core/lib/spree/money.rb#L33). The method appears to be undefined on my development environment.

I don't know if its Spree or the project I'm dealing with. Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Update**: When I run `bundle exec zeus cucumber` I don't get these errors...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just had this issue, followed the advice in: https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/4517

IE: add this to your Gemfile

```
gem 'money', '6.0.1'
```

fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a bug in Spree:

https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/4517

You should specify the following in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'money', '=6.0.1'
```

to work around the issue for now.

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by John worked for me. However, I also had to edit the Gemfile with TextMate (or your own text editor) to make sure the single quotes are correct, as explained in this post: [Gem syntax error questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111158/gem-syntax-error-questions)